# How to get the user ID from a WC_Subscription instance Object

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, userid, woocommerce-subscriptions

I have two functions I need help with that I hope can handle my subscription tasks. The code comments (// ...) is what I'm trying to figure out. If you have other feedback, I'm open to them as well.

This one for completed initial subscription payments and subscription renewals.

```
function payment_made($subscription){
    // How do I get the User ID from subscription? (Definitely need this)
}
add_action("woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete", "payment_made");
```

And this one for when a status is changed, so I can handle manual and system changes either manual overrides or failed/pending/active/whatever status based of payments or switches.

```
function status_update($subscription, $old_status, $new_status){
    // How do I get the User ID from subscription (Definitely need this)
}
add_action("woocommerce_subscription_status_updated", "status_updated");
```

Comment: ok, but in this cause I need help with both. Will ask one at a time next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the user id from the `WC_Subscription` Object, you will use `get_user_id()` method just as you can do with a WC_Order Object:

```
$user_id = $subscription->get_user_id();
```

Tested and works.

Related:

- [How to get the Product ID from a WC_Subscription instance Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63043386/how-to-get-the-product-id-from-a-wc-subscription-instance-object/63043487#63043487)
- [How to get Order Details from a WC_Subscription instance Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63043448/how-to-get-order-details-from-a-wc-subscription-instance-object/63043576#63043576)

Comment: @yanike You need to ask a new question for each: product details and order details (and I will answer).

Comment: Product ID - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63043386/how-to-get-the-product-id-from-a-wc-subscription-instance-object

Comment: Order Details - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63043448/how-to-get-order-details-from-a-wc-subscription-instance-object

Comment: you are awesome! Thanks.