# How to get the Product ID from a WC_Subscription instance Object

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, woocommerce-subscriptions

This one for completed initial subscription payments and subscription renewals.

```
function payment_made($subscription){
    // How do I get the Product ID from subscription? (Definitely need this)
}
add_action("woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete", "payment_made");
```

And this one for when a status is changed, so I can handle manual and system changes either manual overrides or failed/pending/active/whatever status based of payments or switches.

```
function status_update($subscription, $old_status, $new_status){
    // How do I get the Product ID from subscription (Definitely need this)
}
add_action("woocommerce_subscription_status_updated", "status_updated");
```

Comment: Is this answer doesn't work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the product id from the `WC_Subscription` Object, you will need to loop through order items (as you can have many) using the method `get_items()` like:

```
$order_items = $subscription->get_items();

// Loop through order items
foreach ( $order_items as $item_id => $item ) {
    // Get the WC_Product_Subscription Object
    $product = $item->get_product();

    // To get the subscription variable product ID and simple subscription  product ID
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id();

    // To get the variation subscription product ID
    $variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();

    // Or to get the simple subscription or the variation subscription product ID
    $_product_id = $product->get_id();
}
```

Tested and works.

Related:

- [How to get the user ID from a WC_Subscription instance Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63043044/how-to-get-the-user-id-from-a-wc-subscription-instance-object/63043220#63043220)
- [How to get Order Details from a WC_Subscription instance Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63043448/how-to-get-order-details-from-a-wc-subscription-instance-object/63043576#63043576)

Comment: you are awesome! Thanks. Didn't even think about the multiple items since I'm only selling one at the moment.