# How to get Order Details from a WC_Subscription instance Object

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, woocommerce-subscriptions

This one for completed initial subscription payments and subscription renewals.

```
function payment_made($subscription){
    // How do I get the order details?
}
add_action("woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete", "payment_made");
```

And this one for when a status is changed, so I can handle manual and system changes either manual overrides or failed/pending/active/whatever status based of payments or switches.

```
function status_update($subscription, $old_status, $new_status){
    // How do I get the order details?
}
add_action("woocommerce_subscription_status_updated", "status_updated");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the Order details from the `WC_Subscription` Object, you will need first to get the parent ID (which is the order ID) using `get_parent_id()` method:

```
$order_id = $subscription->get_parent_id();
```

Then you will get the WC_Order Object from the order Id using:

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
```

Then to get order details: [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)

Related:

- [How to get the user ID from a WC_Subscription instance Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63043044/how-to-get-the-user-id-from-a-wc-subscription-instance-object/63043220#63043220)
- [How to get the Product ID from a WC_Subscription instance Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63043386/how-to-get-the-product-id-from-a-wc-subscription-instance-object/63043487#63043487)

Comment: you are awesome! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Some details can be obtained directly from the WC_ subscription object using the following methods

```
 $subscription->get_id() //subscription id
 $subscription->get_parent_id() //order id
 $subscription->get_currency()
 $subscription->get_customer_note()
 $subscription->get_prices_include_tax()
 $subscription->get_payment_method()
 $subscription->get_payment_method_title()
 $subscription->get_billing_first_name()
 $subscription->get_billing_last_name()
 $subscription->get_billing_company()
 $subscription->get_billing_address_1()
 $subscription->get_billing_address_2()
 $subscription->get_billing_city()
 $subscription->get_billing_state()
 $subscription->get_billing_postcode()
 $subscription->get_billing_country()
 $subscription->get_billing_email()
 $subscription->get_billing_phone()
 $subscription->get_shipping_first_name()
 $subscription->get_shipping_last_name()
 $subscription->get_shipping_company()
 $subscription->get_shipping_address_1()
 $subscription->get_shipping_address_2()
 $subscription->get_shipping_city()
 $subscription->get_shipping_state()
 $subscription->get_shipping_postcode()
 $subscription->get_shipping_country()
 $subscription->get_order_key()
 $subscription->get_date_created()
 $subscription->get_date_modified()
```